# Advantage of using 64-bit OS and 32-bit application together?

Tags: operating-system, hardware

I'm in the middle of confusion. Say I have a 64-bit OS installed and the application installed is 32-bit. What is the advantage or the disadvantage will I get as a user? Should I better switch to 32-bit OS? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32-bit Windows applications will be able to allocate more memory on 64-bit Windows than on 32-bit. Also, 64-bit Windows is able to use (and let applications use) more physical memory than 32-bit Windows. So, if you have a lot of memory (4+ GB) and want to be able to use more memory, consider using a 64-bit OS.

Comment: And if I don't have that much memory? Say 1-4GB, should I stick to 32-bit OS?

Comment: If you have 3 GB or more, use 64-bit. If 2 GB or less, use 32-bit.